# When I want save crystal report as pdf file, it pop up parameter window again, make me can't save pdf

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report

When I open crystal report and want to save the report as pdf file, it pop up the parameter window and make can't save the pdf files, could you tell me how to solve this problem?

this is my code:

private ReportDocument boReportDocument = null;

```
    private void MyLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

            ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            boReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            string rptFile = this.Page.Request.QueryString["Name"];
            this.Page.Title = this.Page.Request.QueryString["Name"].Replace(".rpt", "");
            boReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Crystal/" + rptFile));
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = boReportDocument;

            connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "XXXX";
            connectionInfo.UserID = "XXXX";
            connectionInfo.Password = "XXXX";
            connectionInfo.ServerName = "XXXX";

            TableLogOnInfos tableLogOnInfos = CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
            foreach (TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo in tableLogOnInfos)
            {
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;

            }


    }


    public ReportsView()
    {
        this.Initialize();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(MyLoad);

    }
```

I use crystal report version 13.0.2000 sp5, (I install sp12 before) same problem.. visual studio 2010

Thanks

Userstation

Answer (score 0):

you can directly export to .pdf using export to httpresponse.

instead of this

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = boReportDocument;
```

try this

```
boReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(
    CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, 
    Response, False, "REPORTNAME")
```